# How do I use log4rs' RollingFileAppender to incorporate rolling logging?

Tags: rust

I am trying to build a logger based on a rolling policy. Below is the closest I was able to implement:

```
let logfile = FileAppender::builder()
    .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::new("{d} {l}::{m}{n}")))
    .build("log/output.log")?;

let config = Config::builder()
    .appender(Appender::builder().build("logfile", Box::new(logfile)))
    .build(Root::builder()
                .appender("logfile")
                .build(LevelFilter::Debug))?;

log4rs::init_config(config)?;
```

This helped me log messages at all levels. However, logging to a file for a long time can be a dangerous proposition. Consequently, I am looking for something which can limit the amount of log data that's preserved. I came across [`RollingFileAppender`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/struct.RollingFileAppender.html), but I am not able to find the proper usage of [`Policy`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/trait.Policy.html).

Please guide me through this. I am mostly looking for programmatic configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can implement it via using [`RollingFileAppender`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/struct.CompoundPolicy.html) [`CompoundPolicy`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/struct.CompoundPolicy.html) , [`FixedWindowRoller`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/roll/fixed_window/struct.FixedWindowRoller.html) and [`SizeTrigger`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/trigger/size/struct.SizeTrigger.html) from `log4rs` crate.

You need to implement the followings in order to create your rolling file logic:

1. `FixedWindowRoller`

Specify `FixedWindowRoller` to roll your log file in a fixed `window_size` like following:

```
let window_size = 3; // log0, log1, log2
let fixed_window_roller = 
FixedWindowRoller::builder().build("log{}",window_size).unwrap();
```

2. `SizeTrigger`

Specify `SizeTrigger` to declare the size limit of the file to trigger the `Roller` like following:

```
let size_limit = 5 * 1024; // 5KB as max log file size to roll
let size_trigger = SizeTrigger::new(size_limit);
```

3. `CompoundPolicy`

Declare `CompoundPolicy` to use it in `RollingFileAppender` like following:

```
let compound_policy = CompoundPolicy::new(Box::new(size_trigger),Box::new(fixed_window_roller));
```

Then in your `Config`, you need to use `RollingFileAppender` in order to get desired behavior.

```rust
let config = Config::builder()
    .appender(
        Appender::builder()
            .filter(Box::new(ThresholdFilter::new(LevelFilter::Debug)))
            .build(
                "logfile",
                Box::new(
                    RollingFileAppender::builder()
                        .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::new("{d} {l}::{m}{n}")))
                        .build("logfile", Box::new(compound_policy))?,
                ),
            ),
    )
    .build(
        Root::builder()
            .appender("logfile")
            .build(LevelFilter::Debug),
    )?;
```

With this implementation, you get a rolling file for the `window size 3` and the `roll size 5KB`

---

If you want to compress the rolled files you can define this in your roller file extension. Instead of `log{}`you can specify extension as `log{}.gz`

However, if you want to enable compression with the log files you need to enable this feature in your `cargo.toml` as following:

```
log4rs = { version ="1.0.0", features = ["gzip"] }
```

---

**Note:** *If you want to have a `custom roller` and `custom trigger` for your own purpose, you can implement your own [`Trigger`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/trigger/trait.Trigger.html) and [`Roller`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.8.3/log4rs/append/rolling_file/policy/compound/roll/trait.Roll.html) from the respective traits*

Comment: This does not work for me--the output all gets written to a file called "logfile" as the path is one of the parameters for RollingFileAppender::builder().build(

Comment: Unless the roller is used in addition to the primary log file?

Comment: Ok it appears that there are two paths. Primary log file path "logfile" and then the rolling file path, which is the 'archive' path. It will fill up primary and then send to archive when that is full.

Comment: @jle yes this is the main idea behind file rolling. You are handling these via 2 parameters as `window size` and `roll size` as I mention on the answer